# Using yeoman in VM causes error...

Tags: web, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am successfully running this on Linux so this is pure Windows problem. Running vagrant fedora box in windows 7 using nvm (node 0.10.35) give me ERR! tar.unpack untar error starting with grunt-contrib-imagemin module.

Addressed issues ran as non sudo as it was suggested in numerous posts. As my installation on Linux flawlessly installs on Windows I run into issues after running yo webapp

vagrant up vagratn ssh nvm use 0.10.35

yo webapp on windows I get these starting errors

first error:

tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/set-immediate-shim/1.0.0/package.tgz second verbose stack error:

EPERM, open '/home/vagrant/workspace/webapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/download/node_modules/download-status/node_modules/object-assign/package.json'

and then it goes crazy on grunt-contrib-imagemin.

I am aware of symlink issues in VM and heard of some long paths issues with grunt-contrib-imagemin but I have no direction how to continue debugging.

node -v v0.10.35 npm -v 2.1.17 yo -v 1.3.3 bower -v 1.3.12 grunt --version grunt-cli v0.1.13 Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I've hit the long path name with npm on windows thing before - Have you tried running yo webapp inside the vm?

Comment: That's what I am doing. This happens when I do it inside VM.

Answer (score 0):

May not be ideal, but I was able to get this working by giving Vagrant user ownership of my project directory.

`sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /link/to/project`